# Binding collection of Threads to ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, listbox

There probably was a topic in which lays the solution for my problem but I've spend too much hours on this so I've decided to ask.

I have a ListView to which I've binded a collection of processes. And I have a ListBox in which I want to place Threads of a selected process. Binding in ListView works, but analogical in ListBox doesn't.

Here's my .xaml:

```xml
<Window x:Class="TaskManager.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window" Height="453" Width="533" Icon="/TaskManager;component/Images/taskmgr.png">
<Grid>
    <ListView Height="276" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="processesView" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="503" ItemsSource="{Binding ProcessList}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProcessName}">
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Click="nameColumnHeader_Click">
                            Name
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}">
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Click="IDColumnHeader_Click">
                            ID
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding BasePriority}">
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Click="priorityColumnHeader_Click">
                            Priority
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Keep alive">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="keepAliveBox" IsChecked="{Binding EnableRaisingEvents}" Checked="keepAliveBox_Checked" Unchecked="keepAliveBox_Unchecked" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <ListBox Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="93,282,0,0" Name="threadBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=processesView, Path=SelectedItem.Threads}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!--<ListBoxItem Content="{Binding}"/>-->
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

After execution I can't see anything in the ListBox but if I click inside something is selected. So if I change the above to Content="TEST" I can see several Labels with "TEST" value. So it seems that I'm binding the name somehow incorrectly.

Here's the .cs part where I set the context:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    processesView.DataContext = this;
    threadBox.DataContext = this;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the [tag:xaml] please?

Comment: In your xaml your already setting the ItemSource of threadBox to processesView SelectedItem, why set the datacontext again in the xaml.cs?

Comment: I've just tried many things I've found in different topics. Commenting it out doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items were invisible but selectable so it was probable that I was binding the wrong thing. And that's the reason. I was binding to Name property of Thread whilst Process has a collection of ProcessThreads which don't have that property. Here's the fix in .xaml:

```xml
    <ListBox Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="93,282,0,0" Name="threadBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=processesView, Path=SelectedItem.Threads}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Id}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Can't wait for XAML debugger in Visual Studio 2015.